# Second parallel streams starts before completing the first

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> fullList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
        List<Integer> toBeLast = Arrays.asList(9,10,11,12);
        Random r = new Random();

        fullList.parallelStream().filter(l->!toBeLast .contains(l)).forEach(l->{
        System.out.println("L1 : " + e);
            try {

                Thread.sleep(Math.abs(r.nextLong() % 1000));
                    System.out.println(l);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException i) {

            }
        });

        toBeLast .parallelStream().forEach(l->{
            System.out.println("L2 : " + e);
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(Math.abs(r.nextLong() % 1000));
                    System.out.println(l);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException i) {

                }
        });

    }
}
```

Expectation - complete 1-8, 13-14 and start 9-12.

The rest call will trigger a sh script in server which will take 15-90 secs each.
Actual - in the server at one point I'm seeing scripts for 2 & 11 are running. I don't see the sysout for 2 yet, and no exception in server as well as the program.

I'm wondering how was that possible to trigger 11 before completing 2?

Comment: l1 and l2 are disjunct? That is there is no value in l1 that is as well in l2?

Comment: you'll need to `join` threads.. you can use `CompletableFuture` or may be `Executors`

Comment: As suggested in the current answer, try to replace the actual call to your REST endpoint with some simple log output and see if you still have this problem. Given your current code there is no indication for anything to go wrong.

Comment: I don't find any problem with this. It will process(print) as you expected... It won't process 11 before 2. Something else must be wrong

Comment: Your updated code is still ok. All elements in l1 will be processed before the ones in l2. How do you call the sh script and how does the script look like? The problem is probably located there.

Comment: The code works as expected.

Comment: Instead of a construct like `Math.abs(r.nextLong() % 1000)` you should use `r.nextInt(1000)`. Besides that, starting scripts in a particular order does not prevent them from running at the same time nor completing in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right in the question. Here is the code that I wrote and in my example, the first stream always completes before the second stream.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
        List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34);
        Random r = new Random();

        l1.parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println("L1 : " + e);
            try {

                Thread.sleep(Math.abs(r.nextLong() % 1000));
            }
            catch(InterruptedException i) {

            }
        });
        l2.parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println("L2 : " + e);
            try {

                Thread.sleep(Math.abs(r.nextLong() % 1000));
            }
            catch(InterruptedException i) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My guess is that you are using an HTTP client library that is doing the activity in the background and because of that the second stream is getting started before first stream finishes.

Comment: thank you. I modified the code to reflect more my exact scenario. Wondering what am I missing.